# How do I add/toggle a class to element in order to switch Hamburger menu to X in order to close and back again

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use vanilla JavaScript to switch the hamburger menu to an X and then back again. I want to only use vanilla js, not JQuery.

I have included the code to show I have tried. I am trying to get the '.open' class to be added/toggle when I "open" the menu. But to no avail.

**Here is my code:**

```js
const navToggle = document.getElementById('nav-toggle');
navToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (navToggle.classList)
    navToggle.classList.add('open');
  else
    navToggle.className += ' ' + open;
  // navToggle.style.display('open');
});
```

```css
*,
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

img.logo-header {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

.header-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.logo-header {
  grid-column: 1;
}


/* Navbar */

.nav-header {
  grid-column: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Navbar Hamburger Menu */

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
}

nav a:hover {
  /* Change Color  */
  color: #000;
}

.nav-toggle:checked~nav {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}

.nav-toggle:checked~nav a {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.nav-toggle-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4em;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 1em;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-toggle-label span,
.nav-toggle-label span::before,
.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  height: .125em;
  width: 2.15em;
  border-radius: .125em;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::before,
.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::before {
  bottom: .5em;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  top: .5em;
}

.open .nav-toggle {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.open .nav-toggle::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .nav-toggle::after {
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper">
  <img class="logo-header" src="./assets/img/logo.png" alt="">

  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
  <nav class="nav-header">
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Ministries</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Book</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label"><span></span></label>

</div>
```

I want the hamburger menu to disappear and turn into an X, then switch back to hamburger if clicked again. Right now, all that is happening is the menu is appearing and disappearing when clicked but nothing else. Would like there to be a transition from a hamburger to X. Nothing super fancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
  const navToggle = document.getElementById('nav-toggle');
  navToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //This is a better way to toggle classes
    navToggle.classList.toggle('open')
  });
```

```css
*, html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

img.logo-header {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

.header-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.logo-header {
  grid-column: 1;
}


/* Navbar */

.nav-header {
  grid-column: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Navbar Hamburger Menu */

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
}

nav a:hover {
  /* Change Color  */
  color: #000;
}

.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}

.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav a {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
}

/* Make middle bar invisible */

.nav-toggle:checked ~ .nav-toggle-label > span {
 background-color: transparent;
}

/* Rotate and translate the top and bottom bar */

.nav-toggle:checked ~ .nav-toggle-label > span::before {
 transform: translateY(0.5em) rotate(45deg)
}

.nav-toggle:checked ~ .nav-toggle-label > span::after {
 transform: translateY(-0.5em) rotate(-45deg)
}

.nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}

/* Fixed height of the box so that it covers the whole switch/button */

.nav-toggle-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.925em;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 1em;
  height: 2.15em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Added transition */

.nav-toggle-label span,
.nav-toggle-label span::before,
.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  height: .125em;
  width: 2.15em;
  border-radius: .125em;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.2s, background-color 0.2s;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::before,
.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::before {
  bottom: .5em;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::after {
  top: .5em;
}

.open .nav-toggle {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.open .nav-toggle::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .nav-toggle::after {
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <img class="logo-header" src="./assets/img/logo.png" alt="">

    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
      <nav class="nav-header">
        <ul>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Ministries</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Book</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label"><span></span></label>

  </div>
```

Here you go:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMoEwX

By using `transform: rotate() translateY()` I make the top and bottom bar into an X and I also make the middle bar invisible.

I also went ahead and fixed the height of the switch/button and your JavaScript.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! I'm not super good at JS and sometimes I get a little confused and all but thanks so much!!!